# How to create boundary with addBoundaryWithIdentifie for Path

Tags: swift, collision, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create a boundary, for my object collision, using Bezier Path. I definitely understand how to use this method, but it is seems that my path is building not as it should be.

```
let firstSurfacePoint = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 120)
let fourthSurfacePoint = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 240)


let center = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 120)
let radius: CGFloat = 120.00
let arcWidth: CGFloat = 20.00

let line =  UIBezierPath()

    line.moveToPoint(self.firstSurfacePoint)
    line.addArcWithCenter(self.center, radius: self.radius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: false)
    line.addLineToPoint(self.fourthSurfacePoint)
    line.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: self.fourthSurfacePoint.x, y: self.fourthSurfacePoint.y-self.radius/2), radius: self.radius/2, startAngle:CGFloat(3*M_PI/2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: true)
    line.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: self.fourthSurfacePoint.x, y: self.fourthSurfacePoint.y-self.radius/2), radius: self.radius/2, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), endAngle:  CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: false)


    let currentPath = CAShapeLayer()
    currentPath.path = line.CGPath
    currentPath.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    currentPath.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    currentPath.lineWidth = 1
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(currentPath)

    collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("curve", forPath: line)
    self.addGravity()
```

There is no problem with collision, but it seems that my path is closing from the last point back to the first part, creating a line between them. 
I didn't use closePath() method, so it is strange, why it is clothing the path.

[Description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8vc9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/40757278/2303865 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006716/how-can-i-prevent-closing-bezier-path

Comment: I'm still using Swift 2.2 (

Comment: they quite similar, but describes a bit another problem